# How to access specific layer(sprites) of a .psb file in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to save/load sprites for my game, and am achieving it by simply getting the path of the asset. Although, whenever trying to save a sprite that is inside of .psb file I simply cannot as it is saved as one singular .psb file. For example, I am getting a **path** for a .png file inside my folder, and it works flawlessly, but, whenever trying to access lets say **head** sprite that is inside of .psb file in my assets folder, I cannot do that.

Any tips for saving/accessing those files and how to achieve it?
Please help :)

Comment: I would avoid packaging psb files in your game

Comment: @Ruzihm what else should I do then? I rig the .psb file and then use it... :/

Comment: I haven't used the psb importer but does it create gameobjects when you import it? Can you move those gameobjects into resources then load those?

Comment: I get something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/wnZAdYR)
One file with many like sprites in it. @Ruzihm

Comment: Is it possible that this is not treated as a `Sprite` but a [`SpriteAtlas`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/U2D.SpriteAtlas.html)?

Comment: Probably yes. I checked the "sprites" in the file and it specifiec something as atlas tag.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you get is not a `Sprite` but a [`SpriteAtlas`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/U2D.SpriteAtlas.html) in which case you could use [`SpriteAtlas.GetSprites`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/U2D.SpriteAtlas.GetSprites.html) to list all sprites and [`SpriteAtlas.GetSprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/U2D.SpriteAtlas.GetSprite.html) to get specific sprite by name/tag.

```
SpriteAtlas theAtlas;

var sprites = new Sprite[theAtlas.spriteCount];
theAtlas.GetSprites(sprites);

var specificSprite = theAtlas.GetSprite("Head");
```